# Plotly: How to plot a multi-line chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I have a 2d list and I want to create a [Plotly multi-line chart](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plot-with-column-encoding-color) to represent this data.

So far I've got this code:

```py
print(len(conv_loss),len(conv_loss[0]))
print(np.array(conv_loss).shape)
conv_loss_df = pd.DataFrame(data=conv_loss, index=namelist, columns=rs)
print(conv_loss_df)
```

which outputs:

```
4 10
(4, 10)
                    0.0       0.1       0.2  ...       0.7       0.8       0.9
mnist          0.020498  0.123125  0.222588  ...  1.122625  1.387823  1.701249
fashion_mnist  0.232772  0.316569  0.433325  ...  1.281240  1.545556  1.830893
cifar10        0.957889  0.851946  0.921106  ...  1.645510  1.815194  2.104631
cifar100       3.516734  3.052485  3.021778  ...  3.688753  3.937770  4.599526
```

I would want the chart to have the x axis be `rs`, the colors be `namelist` and the y axis be the respective data itself.

I have played around with the examples they give for plotly line charts but I just can't seem to get it to work.

The way I've got to work it to not error is:

```py
fig = px.line(conv_loss_df,x=rs)
fig.show()
```

which produces an entirely wrong graph:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired graph can be drawn by targeting the data frame with the given data transposed. This was created with sample data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px # plotly ver 4.14.1
import random

rs = np.arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.1)
namelist = ['mnist', 'Fasion_mnist','cifar10','cifar100']
mnist = np.random.rand(9)
fasion_mnist = np.random.rand(9)
cifar10 = np.random.rand(9)
cifar100 = np.random.rand(9)

conv_loss_df = pd.DataFrame([mnist,fasion_mnist,cifar10,cifar100], index=namelist, columns=rs)
conv_loss_df.T
fig = px.line(conv_loss_df.T)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If I copy and paste the code you just gave, I get a blank graph. This is in an `.ipynb` file so maybe something to do with that?

Comment: I also created and ran this code in jupyterlab and it displays correctly, does the [sample code](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/) on the PLOTLY site display?

Comment: Yes, all the code examples from the their site work as intended, perhaps notably I am using google colab here, I do not know if that would make a difference.

Comment: The version of Google Colaboratory is 4.4.1, and the current latest version is 4.14.1, so why don't you try `pip install -U plotly` to upgrade?

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thankyou so much! (would suggest you add 'make sure to use plotly version > x' to the answer here)

Comment: Yes, it is. I added the version number as a comment to the code.